# Generate random dates with random times between two dates for selected period and frequency

Tags: php, algorithm, date, datetime, email

I have to create a scheduling component that will plan e-mails that need to be sent out. Users can select a start time, end time, and frequency. Code should produce a random moment for every frequency, between start and end time. Outside of office hours.

**Paramaters:**

User can select a period between 01/01/2020 (the start) and 01/01/2021 (the end). In this case user selects a timespan of one exactly year.

User can select a frequency. In this case user selects '2 months'.

**Function:**

Code produces a list of datetimes. The total time (one year) is divided by frequency (2 months). We expect a list of 6 datetimes.

Every datetime is a random moment in said frequency (2 months). Within office hours.

**Result:**

An example result for these paramaters might as follows, with the calculated frequency bounds for clarity:

- [jan/feb] 21-02-2020 11.36
- [mrt/apr] 04-03-2020 16.11
- [mei/jun] 13-05-2020 09.49
- [jul-aug] 14-07-2020 15.25
- [sep-okt] 02-09-2020 14.09
- [nov-dec] 25-12-2020 13.55

--

I've been thinking about how to implement this best, but I can't figure out an elegant solution.

How could one do this using PHP?

Any insights, references, or code spikes would be greatly appreciated. I'm really stuck on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of crappy code but I think it will work as you wish.

```
function getDiffInSeconds(\DateTime $start, \DateTime $end) : int
{
    $startTimestamp = $start->getTimestamp();
    $endTimestamp = $end->getTimestamp();
    
    return $endTimestamp - $startTimestamp;
}

function getShiftData(\DateTime $start, \DateTime $end) : array
{
    $shiftStartHour = \DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $start->format('H:i:s'));
    $shiftEndHour = \DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $end->format('H:i:s'));
    
    $shiftInSeconds = intval($shiftEndHour->getTimestamp() - $shiftStartHour->getTimestamp());
    
    return [
        $shiftStartHour,
        $shiftEndHour,
        $shiftInSeconds,
    ];
}

function dayIsWeekendOrHoliday(\DateTime $date, array $holidays = []) : bool
{
    $weekendDayIndexes = [
        0 => 'Sunday',
        6 => 'Saturday',
    ];
    
    $dayOfWeek = $date->format('w');
    if (empty($holidays)) {
        $dayIsWeekendOrHoliday = isset($weekendDayIndexes[$dayOfWeek]);
    } else {
        $dayMonthDate = $date->format('d/m');
        $dayMonthYearDate = $date->format('d/m/Y');
        $dayIsWeekendOrHoliday = (isset($weekendDayIndexes[$dayOfWeek]) || isset($holidays[$dayMonthDate]) || isset($holidays[$dayMonthYearDate]));
    }
    
    return $dayIsWeekendOrHoliday;
}

function getScheduleDates(\DateTime $start, \DateTime $end, int $frequencyInSeconds) : array
{
    if ($frequencyInSeconds < (24 * 60 * 60)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Frequency must be bigger than one day');
    }
    
    $diffInSeconds = getDiffInSeconds($start, $end);
    
    // If difference between $start and $end is bigger than two days
    if ($diffInSeconds > (2 * 24 * 60 * 60)) {
        // If difference is bigger than 2 days we add 1 day to start and subtract 1 day from end
        $start->modify('+1 day');
        $end->modify('-1 day');
        
        // Getting new $diffInSeconds after $start and $end changes
        $diffInSeconds = getDiffInSeconds($start, $end);
    }
    
    if ($frequencyInSeconds > $diffInSeconds) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Frequency is bigger than difference between dates');
    }
    
    $holidays = [
        '01/01'         => 'New Year',
        '18/04/2020'    => 'Easter 1st official holiday because 19/04/2020',
        '20/04/2020'    => 'Easter',
        '21/04/2020'    => 'Easter 2nd day',
        '27/04'         => 'Konings',
        '04/05'         =>  '4mei',
        '05/05'         =>  '4mei',
        '24/12'         => 'Christmas 1st day',
        '25/12'         => 'Christmas 2nd day',
        '26/12'         => 'Christmas 3nd day',
        '27/12'         => 'Christmas 3rd day',
        '31/12'         => 'Old Year'
    ];
    
    [$shiftStartHour, $shiftEndHour, $shiftInSeconds] = getShiftData($start, $end);
    $amountOfNotifications = floor($diffInSeconds / $frequencyInSeconds);
    $periodInSeconds = intval($diffInSeconds / $amountOfNotifications);
    $maxDaysBetweenNotifications = intval($periodInSeconds / (24 * 60 * 60));
    // If $maxDaysBetweenNotifications is equals to 1 then we have to change $periodInSeconds to amount of seconds for one day
    if ($maxDaysBetweenNotifications === 1) {
        $periodInSeconds = (24 * 60 * 60);
    }
    
    $dates = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $amountOfNotifications; $i++) {
        $periodStart = clone $start;
        $periodStart->setTimestamp($start->getTimestamp() + ($i * $periodInSeconds));
        $seconds = mt_rand(0, $shiftInSeconds);
        
        // If $maxDaysBetweenNotifications is equals to 1 then we have to check only one day without loop through the dates
        if ($maxDaysBetweenNotifications === 1) {
            $interval = new \DateInterval('P' . $maxDaysBetweenNotifications . 'DT' . $seconds . 'S');
            $date = clone $periodStart;
            $date->add($interval);
            
            $dayIsWeekendOrHoliday = dayIsWeekendOrHoliday($date, $holidays);
        } else {
            // When $maxDaysBetweenNotifications we have to loop through the dates to pick them
            $loopsCount = 0;
            $maxLoops = 3; // Max loops before breaking and skipping the period
            do {
                $day = mt_rand(0, $maxDaysBetweenNotifications);
                $periodStart->modify($shiftStartHour);
                $interval = new \DateInterval('P' . $day . 'DT' . $seconds . 'S');
                $date = clone $periodStart;
                $date->add($interval);
                
                $dayIsWeekendOrHoliday = dayIsWeekendOrHoliday($date, $holidays);
                
                // If the day is weekend or holiday then we have to increment $loopsCount by 1 for each loop
                if ($dayIsWeekendOrHoliday === true) {
                    $loopsCount++;
                    
                    // If $loopsCount is equals to $maxLoops then we have to break the loop
                    if ($loopsCount === $maxLoops) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } while ($dayIsWeekendOrHoliday);
        }
        
        // Adds the date to $dates only if the day is not a weekend day and holiday
        if ($dayIsWeekendOrHoliday === false) {
            $dates[] = $date;
        }
    }
    
    return $dates;
}

$start = new \DateTime('2020-12-30 08:00:00', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Sofia'));
$end = new \DateTime('2021-01-18 17:00:00', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Sofia'));
$frequencyInSeconds = 86400; // 1 day

$dates = getScheduleDates($start, $end, $frequencyInSeconds);
var_dump($dates);
```

You have to pass `$start`, `$end` and `$frequencyInSeconds` as I showed in example and then you will get your random dates. Notice that I `$start` and `$end` must have hours in them because they are used as start and end hours for shifts. Because the rule is to return a date within a shift time only in working days. Also you have to provide frequency in seconds - you can calculate them outside the function or you can change it to calculate them inside. I did it this way because I don't know what are your predefined periods.

This function returns an array of \DateTime() instances so you can do whatever you want with them.

**UPDATE 08/01/2020:**
Holidays now are part of calculation and they will be excluded from returned dates if they are passed when you are calling the function. You can pass them in `d/m` and `d/m/Y` formats because of holidays like Easter and in case when the holiday is on weekend but people will get additional dayoff during the working week.

**UPDATE 13/01/2020:**
I've made updated code version to fix the issue with infinite loops when `$frequencyInSeconds` is shorter like 1 day. The new code used few functions `getDiffInSeconds`, `getShiftData` and `dayIsWeekendOrHoliday` as helper methods to reduce code duplication and cleaner and more readable code

Comment: Super! We are getting close! How does this deal with 28/30/31 day months and holidays? Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: I don't think that there are problems with that - first about 28/30/31 - as you can see here `$interval = new \DateInterval('P' . $day . 'DT' . $seconds . 'S');` I've made a interval of days and seconds which are added to cloned period date here `$date->add($interval);` with php DateTime class will handle exact date and it will be 100% valid date :) About holidays - do you see a requirement like that in your question? I will update my post later with ability to exclude holidays from generated dates.

Comment: @user2863494 handling of holidays was added and my answer was updated

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. It look's good! I've awarded the bounty for your work. I will do some further testing with several input parameters and accept your response as the correct answer accordingly.

Comment: @user2863494 please mark the answer as "accepted answer"

Comment: the code is in a infinite loop in the do;while statement. $start=2020-12-30, $end=2021-01-18,$freq=86400.

Comment: @user2863494 give me a code example in pastebin or something like that

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Z3SaWX1P - I think $dayIsWeekendOrHoliday never gets unset or in some specific cases the $i is not incrementing.

Comment: on a holiday the do/while keeps looping, since $dayIsWeekendOrHoliday is always true, and it will never go to the next date ($dayIsMonthDate)

Comment: I understand your code a bit better now. It attempts to find a replacement date when dayIsWeekendOrHoliday. It breaks however when the frequency is set to one day/every day.

Comment: @user2863494 I've made update of my code to prevent infinite looping. Also I've added few comments for easier understanding. P.S. - Sorry for delayed response

Comment: Hi thanks so much! One more thing I've been struggling with is that sometimes the amount of notifications is wrong. e.g. $start=01/01/2021, $end=01/01/2022,$frequency=15778000 (6 months) - it will yield one notification instead of expected two because $diffInSeconds / $frequencyInSeconds will evaluate to something like 1.98. Is rounding this number up a solution? Thanks.

Comment: @user2863494 you can round up with ceil() or to use normal rounding with round() but this will cause unexpected behavior because this calculation must give you the exact amount of notification rounded to the down whole number not to upper one

Comment: yeah rounding does not work. It will produce too many notifications. But rounding down shows to little (see example). How could we go about streamlining this?

Comment: I've tried some various things like rounding up from 1.90 (and the rest lower) but I can't get it right. Frequencies in the software are day, 1,2,3 weeks, 1,2,3,4,5,6 months and year. Maybe doing seconds calculations arent the best way? Greatly appreciate your time and effort

Comment: Nope the seconds are the best solution but since the beginning you've changed two times the task. Here you can ask some help not FREE freelancer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just asking for suggestions on how to generate a list of repeating (2 weekly) dates with a random time between say 9am and 5pm? Is that right?

If so - something like this (untested, pseudo code) might be a starting point:

```
$start    = new Datetime('1st January 2021');
$end      = new Datetime('1st July 2021');
$day_start = 9;
$day_end = 17;

$date = $start;
$dates = [$date]; // Start date into array
while($date < $end) {
            
    $new_date = clone($date->modify("+ 2 weeks"));
    $new_date->setTime(mt_rand($day_start, $day_end), mt_rand(0, 59));
        
    $dates[] = $new_date;
}

var_dump($dates);
```

Comment: This does not yield de wanted results. It picks a random time every 2 weeks from the start date. I'm looking for a random day and time, within those two weeks. I will update the original question. Thank you for your time, it is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Steve's anwser seems good, but you should consider 2 additional things

1. holiday check, in the while after first $new_date line, like:

> ```
> $holiday = array('2021-01-01',    '2021-01-06', '2021-12-25');
> if (!in_array($new_date,$holiday))
> ```

2. also a check if date is a office day or a weekend in a similar way as above with working days as an array.

Comment: Good suggestion - but would need to be careful when doing the in_array check as the $new_date would be a dateTime object rather than a string. Could be dong with if(!in_array($new_date->format('Y-m-d'), $holiday)) though.

Comment: Smart of you to point out the holidays. I will see if how I will deal with this. Please see the updated question if you will, I've explained better what I mean by frequency.

Comment: you should do it as an object it these days - thats a fact. at this moment I have in mind only a math calculated method with some random modified time.
Some time ago I had similar problem with holiday days for time managment in my app. But did it without an object and a simple array.